# ¿Alguien sabe por qué me afecta el cambio de color al segundo botón?

Tags: swift, botón

Estoy aprendiendo a usar los botones en Swift y estoy cambiando de color varios por separados al momento de pulsarse. El problema es que cuando pulso el segundo botón también me cambia de color el primero, y lo veo algo extraño ya que en teoría son dos funciones diferentes y una no debería afectar a la otra. ¿Alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando?

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  EjemploProyecto
//
//  Created by Mario Miranda  on 17/4/22.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    //Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        //Buttons
        myButton.backgroundColor = .green
        button2.backgroundColor = .blue
    }

    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    
        if myButton.backgroundColor == .green
        {
            myButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        } else
        {
            myButton.backgroundColor = .green
        }
    
    }

    @IBAction func buttonAction2(_ sender: Any) {
    
        if button2.backgroundColor == .blue
        {
            button2.backgroundColor = .gray
        } else
        {
            button2.backgroundColor = .blue
        }
    
    } 
}
```

Comment: En el inspector de objetos a lado derecho en Xcode puedes ver las conexiones de los botones con el `ViewController`, si copias y pegas los botones, se copian esas conexiones y solo debes eliminar la que no corresponda.

Comment: Gracias! A ver si lo consigo solucionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás usando Storyboards ve a tu UI correspondiente y con clic derecho sobre el UI Component podes chequear las conexiones con tu ViewController, en su caso, elimina las que no correspondan.
O bien elimina todas y luego vuelves a establecer usando el ***Asistente***.
(Para mí es la forma mas efectiva y limpia de hacerlo).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Parte superior derecha de Storyboard

Un último consejo: establece el type correspondiente al UIObjects que uses, en este caso `UIButton` en vez de `Any`.

Comment: Haces referencia al `IBAction`? Por qué debe ser `UIButton` y no `Any`?

Comment: Si! A pesar de que `Any` significa cualquier tipo es limitado. Si un Button es identificado como `Any`, no vas a poder acceder las propiedades del UIButton. Como por ejemplo `sender.tag`, `sender.isHidden`, `sender.backgroundColor`, `sender.currentTitle`, etc.
Asimismo especificar el tipo permite al sistema conocer que cantidad de recursos necesita para ese tipo UI Component. (Eficiencia en el uso de los recursos).

Comment: Eso es válido cuando varios botones llaman a una misma función. Así puedes identificar y realizar alguna acción dependiendo de qué botón hizo tap. En el caso del código es un `IBAction` propio del botón que agregas.